# vHost.exe dejo de funcionar WinForms c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013

Llevo ya unos cuantos dias trabajando en un programa que se conecta a un servidor para recuperar cierta información y posteriormente la imprime. El problema que tengo es que cuando imprimo en una impresora standard o en un PDF el programa funciona bién pero esta información la debo imprimir con una impresora POSLAB, que carga papel de 80x420mm. Cuando escojo esta impresora para imprimir la información el programa peta y sale el mensaje de error (vHost.exe dejo de funcionar). Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2013.

Adjunto el código que hace la gestión de la impresión:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.uni != null)
    {
        clsVoucher objVoucher = new clsVoucher();
        objVoucher.Note = this.nota;
        objVoucher.ExpireMinutes = this.minuts;
        uni.CreateVoucher(ref objVoucher);
        enviaAImprimir(dispositiu, objVoucher.VoucherCode);
        //MessageBox.Show("Nova connexió, contrasenya: " + objVoucher.VoucherCode);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        label3.BringToFront();
}
private void enviaAImprimir(Dispositiu dispositiu, string p)
{
    this.contrasenyaObtinguda = p;
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "POSLAB TP805";
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 25;
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 25;
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 25;
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 25;
    //printDocument.DocumentName = "ticketPrint.txt";
    PaperSize midaRoll = new PaperSize("midaTiquets", 314, 1653);
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = midaRoll;
    if (!printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    {
        string msg = String.Format("Can't find printer \"{0}\".", printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Print Error");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //printDialog.Document = printDocument; //add the document to the dialog box...        
        printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(PrintingVoucherEvent);//add an event handler that will do the printing 
        //printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperA3", 1180, 1660);
        printDocument.Print();
    }
}
public void PrintingVoucherEvent(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
    format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up
    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 5;
    int startY = 10;
    int offset = 40;
    //MOSTRA LES DUES CAPÇALERES I EL TITOL//
    graphic.DrawString(" Proves de funcionament", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
    graphic.DrawString(dispositiu.header1, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
    graphic.DrawString(dispositiu.header2, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
    graphic.DrawString("----------------------------------", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5; //make the spacing consistent
    //MOSTRA LA NOVA CONTRASENYA I ALTRA INFORMACIO//
    graphic.DrawString("Connexio al dispositiu: " + dispositiu.name, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
    graphic.DrawString("Contrasenya generada: " + this.contrasenyaObtinguda, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
    graphic.DrawString(dispositiu.footer1, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
    graphic.DrawString(dispositiu.footer2, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5; //make the spacing consistent  

    graphic.Dispose();
}
```

Cabe mencionar que no se me tiene permitido usar frameworks como CrystalReports u otros para imprimir esta información...

Comment: Bueno, yo lo primero que te recomendaría es usar un `try/catch` para ver exactamente donde pude venir el problema. Con la información que nos das es practicamente imposible que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, gracias igualmente. El problema no lo podia resolver con un try catch (o almenos no sabia donde colocarlo) ya que el error de vHost lo que hace es parar completamente la aplicación al momento de llamar a Print(). Este error es de Visual Studio o del NetFramework con el que se basa ya que he ejecutando la aplicación una vez compilada sin el visual studio y ha funcionado sin hacer ningun canvio.